# How to check if each minute in a day has a row in the MySQL database?

Tags: php, mysql, bigdata

I currently have

```
SELECT *, COUNT(*) as `numrows`
FROM `data`
WHERE `datetime`
    BETWEEN '2014-11-04 00:00:00' AND '2014-11-04 23:59:59'
AND `project_id` = 1
GROUP BY
 DATE(`datetime`),
 HOUR(`datetime`),
 MINUTE(`datetime`)
```

Now, this'll return all rows, with some having duplicates so numrows will be 2. But, I want to verify if each minute has a row, so I can verify that the measurements are still properly coming in.

Now, I've thought about looping through the results, adding each returned datetime to an array:

```
while($s = $select->fetch_assoc()) {
 $availableTimes[] = $s['datetime'];
}
```

Then, looping through an array filled with the minutes of the day, but this is very intensive I suppose, especially when you've got 500, 1000, 5000, or even 30000 ids to go through. What would be the best way of going about this be?

Comment: I would join it onto a calendar table which would contain all minutes. That way you can show 0 counts as well when the row is missing.

Comment: count how many distinct records there are, and do a time-diff between the two datetime values. That'll give you the total number of minutes between the two datetimes, and the count will give you how many records there are. If the two values differ, then you're missing minutes somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

If you only get one row for every minute in the day (using group by) you can just use the number of rows you get.
you should have 24*60 results for your query every day (as I understand that's all you need..?)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a temporary table with the hours and minutes like this. You remove any duplicates by using DISTINCT.

```
SELECT DISTINCT HOUR(`datetime`) AS HOUR, MINUTE(`datetime`) AS MINUTE
FROM `data`
WHERE `datetime`
    BETWEEN '2014-11-04 00:00:00' AND '2014-11-04 23:59:59'
AND `project_id` = 1
```

then you can count the numbers of rows in the temporary table by adding a select count(*) on the outside like this

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT HOUR(`datetime`) AS HOUR, MINUTE(`datetime`) AS MINUTE
FROM `data`
WHERE `datetime`
    BETWEEN '2014-11-04 00:00:00' AND '2014-11-04 23:59:59'
AND `project_id` = 1) AS TEMP
```

If there are rows for all hours and minutes, the result should be 1440 (24*60).

Answer (score 0):

you can use a procedure like this to create a table for each minutes.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `make_intervals`(startdate timestamp, enddate timestamp, intval integer, unitval varchar(12))
BEGIN


   declare thisDate timestamp;
   declare nextDate timestamp;
   set thisDate = startdate;




   drop temporary table if exists time_intervals;
   create temporary table if not exists time_intervals
      (
      interval_start timestamp,
      interval_end timestamp
      );




   repeat
      select
         case unitval
            when 'MICROSECOND' then timestampadd(MICROSECOND, intval, thisDate)
            when 'SECOND'      then timestampadd(SECOND, intval, thisDate)
            when 'MINUTE'      then timestampadd(MINUTE, intval, thisDate)
            when 'HOUR'        then timestampadd(HOUR, intval, thisDate)
            when 'DAY'         then timestampadd(DAY, intval, thisDate)
            when 'WEEK'        then timestampadd(WEEK, intval, thisDate)
            when 'MONTH'       then timestampadd(MONTH, intval, thisDate)
            when 'QUARTER'     then timestampadd(QUARTER, intval, thisDate)
            when 'YEAR'        then timestampadd(YEAR, intval, thisDate)
         end into nextDate;

      insert into time_intervals select thisDate, timestampadd(MICROSECOND, -1, nextDate);
      set thisDate = nextDate;
   until thisDate > enddate
   end repeat;
end


call make_intervals('2014-11-04 00:00:00' ,'2014-11-04 23:59:59',1,'MINUTE');
```

than left join your table to timer_intervals table and find missings

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to generate a range of temp rows, one for each minute of the day you are interested in (1440 rows). Then you LEFT OUTER JOIN you data to this, and count the number of rows found for that data time on the data table.

```
SELECT aDateTime, COUNT(data.datetime)
FROM
(
    SELECT DATE_ADD('2014-11-04 00:00:00', INTERVAL a.Mnt + b.Mnt * 10 + c.Mnt * 100 + d.Mnt * 1000 MINUTE) AS aDateTime
    FROM (SELECT 0 AS Mnt UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) a
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 AS Mnt UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) b
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 AS Mnt UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) c
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 AS Mnt UNION SELECT 1) d
    WHERE (a.Mnt + b.Mnt * 10 + c.Mnt * 100 + d.Mnt * 1000) < 1440
) sub0
LEFT OUTER JOIN `data` 
ON sub0.aDateTime = data.datetime
AND data.project_id = 1
GROUP BY aDateTime
```